# c++ conjuntive normal form regex

Tags: c++, regex

I want to build a regex to say is a expression is in the conjunctive normal form (CNF).

An expression E is in CNF when:

- all its clauses are in the format `(V1 ∨ V2 ∨ ... ∨ Vn)`
- between the clauses Ci, there is only &, that is: `E = C1 & C2 & ... & Ck`
- the variables V1, V2, ... can only be `{P, Q, R, S, ~P, ~Q, ~R, ~S}`

An example: `E = (P ∨ Q) & (Q ∨ R ∨ S) & (R ∨ Q)`

How can I write such regex (without spaces)?

---

I guess it must be something like:

```
regex reg("[(~?[PQRS]{1}[v~?[PQRS]{1}]*)&]*(~?[PQRS]{1}[v~?[PQRS]{1}]*)");
```

but it gives me regex_error.

Comment: Question: how do I drive in a screw with a hammer? Answer: use a screwdriver. More on point: write a parser. It's not that hard.

Comment: I could write a parser indeed, but I'm looking for a regex, as I'm not fully into c++ regex syntax yet, seems better to ask about a new thing than do what I'm already able to. I'm asking for curiosity, not because I need to.

Comment: Doing that with a regex is hard if you allow expressions like:
E = (P ∨ (P∨Q)) because now  you have non regular syntax.

Comment: sure this is an issue but I'm not going this deep into the problem, but if it was necessary, you can only delete any `(` and `)` from the interior of any clauses and remove all spaces from all clauses

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was using `(` and `)` incorrectly.

Answer is:

```
regex reg("(\\(~?[PQRS](v~?[PQRS])*\\)&)*\\(~?[PQRS](v~?[PQRS])*\\)");
```